# List the Record's element\fields

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

Is it possible to get the list of a record's elements or fields 
similar to a list of a class's published properties via type info ?

Thanks !

Comment: It is always wise to include the Delphi version in your question, especially with questions about feature specific issues (the RTTI has been overhauled in Delphi 2010) like this question.

Answer (score 8):

Depends of your delphi version, if you are using delphi 2010 o newer you can use the New rtti enhancements.

check this code

```
program ProjectTestRtti;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils;

type
  MyRecord=record
   Field1 : integer;
   Field2 : boolean;
   Field3 : string;
  end;

var
 ctx   : TRttiContext;
 t     : TRttiType;
 field : TRttiField;
begin
 try
     ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
     for field in ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(MyRecord)).GetFields do
     begin
       t := field.FieldType;
       writeln(Format('Field : %s : Type : %s',[field.Name,field.FieldType.Name]));
     end;
 except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
 end;

  Readln;
end.
```